# Username of social network

Tags: php, jquery, .htaccess

I need to set username for my website..
like i have a profile id of user say `localhost/ajax/profile.php?id=27`
I need to change it like `localhost/ajax/xyz`

How to achieve it? Please give me valuable link or show me the right way to go or help me out.

i am totally newbie in this town so please help me from 0.
i mean can i have to make php file before applying .htcaccess ? if yes then what to write on that php file?

suppose a person choose a username "abc" so how can the script identify that `localhost/ajax/profile.php?id=111` is **"abc"** and we need to rewrite `localhost/ajax/abc`

In summary : how to make username like Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Use .htaccess to hide your file name.php extension

```
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine On  # enables url rewriting

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  # if requested uri is not directory (!-d)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f # and if there is a file named URI+'.php' (-f)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php # then if there is any thing in uri then rewrite it as uri+'.php'
```

Comment: Hi @Jenni, #jQuery Angry Bird is right, you can use .htaccess in order to achieve your need

Comment: he said to hide .php extension. but my question is different @JothiKannan

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.htaccess` to re-structure your links. You need to create`.htaccess` if its already not there inside your main folder. You can try this out:

```
RewriteRule localhost/ajax/(.*) localhost/ajax/profile.php?id=$1 [PT,L,B]
```

Remember that on RewriteRule, you can't use any php scripts. So, You can't rewrite `localhost/ajax/profile.php?id=27` to `localhost/ajax/xyz` readily. You need to pass `localhost/ajax/profile.php?id=xyz` and above rule will work fine.

Learn more about `.htaccess` RewriteRule from [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule).

Comment: ok..ummm suppose a person choose a username "abc" so how can the script identify that localhost/ajax/profile.php?id=111 is "abc" and we need to rewrite localhost/ajax/abc  ???

Comment: @Jenni , hello madem , you can do simple things with htaccess without any doubt , But here you want to get user Name with ID that  is done with PHP code . HOW are you going to communicate PHP with HTACCESS ?

Comment: You can pass your link as localhost/ajax/profile.php?id=111&name=abc. Then you can use RewriteRule as:
'RewriteRule localhost/ajax/(.*) localhost/ajax/profile.php?id=$2&name=$1 [PT,L]'

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird You can't do PHP things on .htaccess. The thing you can do is pass the structured PHP url string and manage that on .htaccess according to RewriteRule.

Answer (score 0):

u can do it with .htaccess url rewrite method.

it will convert ur url localhost/ajax/profile.php?id=111 to localhost/ajax/111

after then u can also modify to localhost/ajax/myusername
try given link and enjoy 100% satisfied answer

http://www.9lessons.info/2009/11/pretty-urls-with-htaccess-file.html

here u will find some extra tools for ur social network